# MySQL how to count duplicate items on invoice?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Consider the following table:

```
id, invoice_number, item_number,  qty,  price
1   5000            200           1     4.50 
2   5000            201           2     5.50
3   5000            201           1     5.75 
2   5000            202           1     5.50
3   5000            202           1     5.75 
4   5000            203           1     6.00
```

How can I get the following result:

```
invoice, item, count
5000,    200,    1
5000,    201,    2    
5000,    202,    2
5000,    203,    1
```

I know I can group by the invoice number, but then I cannot simply count the invoices, or I will lose their name.  Additionally I would love to know if they have a different price, even if it was just a flag, however I am thinking to get that level of detail I might as well put this in a script and loop through the items, its just that my data set is very large, and id love to do it with pure SQL :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happened to item 2-3?  Why does 202 have a "count" of 1?

Comment: oops, ill revise, I added some extra rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your exact desired output:

```
select invoice_number, item_number, count(*)
  from tbl
 group by invoice_number, item_number
```

To get your desired output along with the number of unique prices within the group, and what those prices are:

```
select invoice_number,
       item_number,
       count(*) as num_rows,
       count(distinct price) as num_prices,
       group_concat(distinct price) as prices
  from tbl
 group by invoice_number, item_number
```